# Php mysql query not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble with my script. I know that the database has two rows and it is not outputting. I don't think I'm getting an data for my query. Maybe I am doing something wrong. I trying to output contents. Maybe another pair of eyes would help?

```
<?php


$host = "blah. Com";
$database = "blah";
$user = "blah";
$password = "blah";

$con =mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);

if(!$con)
{
echo "Could not connect: " . $database;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM CreditCards";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<select name=\"word\">";


while($ary = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<option value=\"" . $ary[cc_id] . "\">" . $ary[type] . "-" . $ary[last_four] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Sorry in advance about the formatting.  I  on my mobile device...

Comment: Try echoing this: mysqli_error($con) and write what error message you are receiving.

Comment: Why is it people never check the result of a query? Try `if (($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) == false) {echo "SQL error:".mysqli_error;}`

Comment: @Mike W: We don't check the result of a query, because we like to put our little pinky to the corner of our mouth, Dr. Evil style, and say "I just assume it will all go to plan. What?"  :)  But we do check if the connection was made, echo out a message if it wasn't. Then, whether or not the connection was successful, we proceed to execute a query on that connection. "I just assume the query will work without a connection. What?" :)

Comment: Is it showing any error that we may think on? or a blank page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `mysqli_fetch_array` instead of `mysql_fetch_array` at your while loop?